# How to debug http calls on Android devices?

Tags: android, debugging

I'm writing a Lovefilm client for Android, and it's not going too badly except I keep having problems with the remote calls to retrieve data from the API.

Does anyone have any tips for debugging remote calls like this? Can I tcpdump on Android or is there a native way of doing it?

For example, I'm using the Scribe-java library for OAuth to access the Lovefilm API, I can authenticate find and retrieve a list of films on the users account fine when the device is running Gingerbread, but trying to retrieve the accessToken on Froyo causes a blank response & and apparent response code of -1, I'd like to be able to see what's going on under the cvers their.

Another example I'd like to be able to the raw http for is trying to run a search, I get and IOError that says "*Received authentication challenge is null*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Fiddler (http-proxy for debugging http calls) with the android emulator in these cases. Just start the proxy, and start the emulator with the correct proxy address (-http-proxy ).

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler is the most useful option. On the emulator @Scythe answer will work, but on a real device you will need to set the proxy in the Apache Http Client. The following code will do that:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("youripaddr", 8888); 
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

If you are using https, fiddler is not so useful. In that case can enable the build in logging support in Apache Http Client. The following code does that:

Headers only:

```
java.util.logging.Logger apacheHeaderLog = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers");       
apacheHeaderLog.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

Headers & Wire:

```
java.util.logging.Logger apacheWireLog = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire");
apacheWireLog.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

Note that this will have to have a java.util.logging [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Handler.html) configured at finest level and the default handler is configured to log to logcat, which will filter DEBUG (finest) entries by default.

Answer (score 1):

If your system can share the wi-fi connection you should be able to route packets from any device through your system and then using wireshark you can get monitor your calls or get a tcpdump.

Also , and more importantly , it would be best if you log your network calls and responses as suggested by @Matthew

Windows 7 wi-fi connection sharing : http://www.winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/windows-7-tip-of-the-week-use-wireless-hosted-networking-to-share-an-internet-connection-wirelessly.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since I always run into similar troubles and it seems a lot of people having the same issues over and over again I wrote up a quick [tutorial for debugging client-server communication by using netcat and cURL](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/04/debugging-client-server-communication.html).

That of course only works for the simplified case that you always 'fake' on side of the connection.

For eavesdropping you can use tools like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Which will definitely be easier if you're able to run the server instance directly on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Stetho is a great tool from FB which helps in debugging android Apps. You can have access to local data and have a check on your network using this.

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/